# Confused about use of optim in R. Simple example

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit some data to a custom function, using a simple least min squared approach. I've defined both the custom function and the error function, and I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax for "optim".

Here is an example:

```
#Create some data based on the function f(x) = x^4

Range = c(0:10)
Output = Range^4
ActualData = data.frame(Range,Output)

#Define custom function 

MyFun = function(x,a) 
{
 x^a
}


#Define error function, which calculates the residual sum of squares 

ErrFun = function(Data,x,a)
{
sum((MyFun(x,a)-Data)^2)
}

#My failed attempt at using "optim", using exponent of 3 as a starting point

optim(par = c(Output,Range,3), ErrFun, data = ActualData)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in fn(par, ...) :
 unused argument (data = list(Range = 0:10, Output = c(0, 1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000)))
```

I get the sense that this has something to do with the way I'm defining par. I gather that par should consist of parameters which the optimization function will try to search for, so as to minimize the value of ErrFun. But the ErrFun function itself passes, in addition to "a", two other parameters which aren't meant to be optimized (Data, and x). I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and would really appreciate some help!

Comment: In one place you used the spelling `data` and in another `Data`?

Comment: I used that based on [this tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-use-optim-in-r/), thinking that the lowercase data was the syntax for the optim function (similar to lowercase "par"). I think that was a wrong assumption, though. 

I used this line and I think it works now:

`optim(par = 3, ErrFun, Data = Output,x = Range)`

thanks for the push in the right direction :)

Comment: Never forget, `?optim`.  Always `?optim`.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, I have been trying to understand the documentation, but I find it really difficult to grasp. I'm not even sure why my current syntax works. For example, from the documentation:

optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,)

I haven't specified a gradient. I specified par, and fn. In my code, the stuff that comes after "ErrFun," is "Data = Output, x = Range". 

Why isn't the program confused? After all, it should be expecting me to specify the gradient right after I specify the function.